# Angular $state.go reload: true?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Can somebody explain what exactly does `reload: true` when using it with `$state.go` in Angular ui-router?

Sometimes my data is not updated when I use `$state.go` after editing an object, and when I `reload: true` it magically works. I know it must reload something, but what exactly and in which scenario it makes sense to use it?

Comment: It reloads the UI-Router controls I believe, so anytime you want the route to be re-evaluated from the beginning, use it.